How to fix "Component <Anonymous>: setup function returned a promise, but no <Suspense> boundary"?
I see a warning in the console.log that I want to omit to avoid unwanted side effects.

Component : setup function returned a promise, but no
 boundary was found in the parent component tree. A
component with async setup() must be nested in a <Suspense> in order
to be rendered

The reason why I see this is the await-statement when I await a promise from a pinia-store:
<script setup async lang="ts">

const libraryStore = useLibraryStore()
// other declarations

await libraryStore.loadArticles(lang, options)  

</script>

What is best practice to deal with asynchronous functions? In my case, loadArticles is performing some AJAX-Requests and so I have to wait for the response.

The warning means what it says. The component should be used only inside .

@EstusFlask then it changes into " is an experimental feature and its API will likely change.". I don't want to use experimental features. Asynchronous requests are not new in 2024,. Why do we need suddenly a Suspense?

This is the intention, it's labeled as experimental for ages and is not going to break. We need it because it's a powerful feature that allows you to write the code you listed. Otherwise you have to resort the way this was handled in vue 2 instead of 3
